# Unity: Cannot obtain information from an HDR display. HDR is not enabled in the player settings for this project

Tags: unity-game-engine, hdr

I am trying to enable HDR output in Unity 2020.3.2f1 by calling [RequestHDRModeChange](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HDROutputSettings.RequestHDRModeChange.html)

```
HDROutputSettings.main.RequestHDRModeChange(true);
```

but I receive an exception saying:

```
Cannot obtain information from an HDR display. HDR is not enabled in the player settings for this project.
```

I am not at all sure what do I need to enable. I have all Graphics Tiers set to `Use HDR` = Yes and `HDR Mode` = FP16. In player settings I added `DisplayP3` Color Gamut. I do not see any other related setting.

I get the same exception in both Windows 10 x64 (in the editor) and in Android 9 (API 28) phone Asus Rog Phone II with HDR10 screen and [wide gamut](https://developer.android.com/training/wide-color-gamut) capability.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out there is a setting in the Player settings to enable the HDR output but it is only shown for the Windows platform. There does not seem to be any support for HDR output on Android.